# SQL Server Best Date Matches Between Data Sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to populate `@firstParty` with the *best matches* from `@thirdParty`.

For a record to match, `@firstParty.Registered` has to be within 31 days of `@thirdParty.Registered`.

In addition, any record from `@thirdParty` cannot be associated with more than one record in `@firstParty`.

I want to do this as efficiently as possible.  SQL Server version is 2008, so features introduced after that can't be used.

This sample code is simplification of the actual code, which I can't post:

```
declare @firstParty table
(
    FirstPartyId integer identity,
    Registered date,

    MinThirdPartyId integer,
    MinThirdPartyRegistered date

);

insert into @firstParty (Registered)
values
('1/1/2017'), ('2/1/2017'), ('3/1/2017'), ('4/1/2017'), ('5/1/2017'), ('6/1/2017');

/*
dates in @firstParty and @thirdParty are not guaranteed to be unique 
in all scenarios
*/

declare @thirdParty table
(
    ThirdPartyId integer identity,
    Registered date
);

insert into @thirdParty (Registered)
values
('03/02/2017'), ('04/30/2017');


declare @x integer = 1;
while @x <= (select max(FirstPartyId) from @firstParty) begin

    declare @MinRegistered date = null;

    --get minimum third party date within 31 days of registered date, that hasn't been used
    select
        @MinRegistered = min(tp.Registered)     
    from
        @firstParty fp
        join @thirdParty tp on
            fp.Registered between dateadd(d, -31, tp.Registered) and dateadd(d, 31, tp.Registered)
        left join @firstParty used on tp.ThirdPartyId = used.MinThirdPartyId
    where
        fp.FirstPartyId = @x
        and used.MinThirdPartyId is null;

    declare @MinThirdPartyId integer = null;

    --get earliest ID of third party record with @MinRegistered
    select top 1
        @MinThirdPartyId = tp.ThirdPartyId
    from
        @firstParty fp
        join @thirdParty tp on
            tp.Registered = @MinRegistered
        left join @firstParty used on tp.ThirdPartyId = used.MinThirdPartyId
    where
        fp.FirstPartyId = @x
        and used.MinThirdPartyId is null
    order by
        tp.Registered,
        tp.ThirdPartyId;


    update @firstParty
    set
        MinThirdPartyId = @MinThirdPartyId,
        MinThirdPartyRegistered = @MinRegistered
    where
        FirstPartyId = @x;


    set @x = @x + 1;

end;


select
    fp.FirstPartyId,
    fp.Registered,
    fp.MinThirdPartyId,
    fp.MinThirdPartyRegistered
from
    @firstParty fp;
```

Here are the results that I want:

```
FirstPartyId Registered MinThirdPartyId MinThirdPartyRegistered
------------ ---------- --------------- -----------------------
1            2017-01-01 NULL            NULL
2            2017-02-01 NULL            NULL
3            2017-03-01 1               2017-03-02
4            2017-04-01 NULL            NULL
5            2017-05-01 2               2017-04-30
6            2017-06-01 NULL            NULL
```

An approach that first populates all matches and then removes the non-optimal matches will not work, because if a @firstParty's optimal @thirdParty's record is removed, there could be a different record in @thirdParty that is still an acceptable match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

**Example**

```
Select A.FirstPartyId
      ,A.Registered
      ,MinThirdPartyId = B.ThirdPartyId
      ,MinThirdPartyRegistered = B.Registered
 From  @firstParty A
 Left  Join (
                Select B1.*
                      ,MinPartyID =B2.FirstPartyID
                 From  @thirdParty B1
                 Cross Apply (
                                Select Top 1 with ties *
                                 From @firstParty
                                 Where abs(DateDiff(DAY,B1.Registered,Registered))<=31
                                 Order By abs(DateDiff(DAY,B1.Registered,Registered)) 
                             ) B2
            ) B
  on (B.MinPartyID=A.FirstPartyId)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @BenOsborne Happy to help